# Ordenar los elementos de un navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3

¿Cómo puedo colocar los elementos de un `navbar` a medida que queden bien colocados y que el último elemento quede al final del `navbar`? Sobra un espacio entre el último elemento y el final del `navbar` y no se ve muy bien.

Éste es mi código (pulsar en "Página completa" para ver el error):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse " >
  <div class="navbar-header " id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills ">
       <li role="presentation" class="pull-left active"><a href="index.html"><h4> INICIO</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="pull-left active"><a href="pacas.html"><h4> VENTA DE ROPA EN PACAS</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="active active"><a href="varon.html"><h4> VENTA DE ROPA PARA VARON</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="dama.html"><h4> VENTA DE ROPA PARA DAMA</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="pull-right active"><a href="nino.html"><h4>VENTA DE ROPA PARA NIÑO</h4></a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

La visualización queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Quieres que los elementos tengan su propio ancho o está bien si todos acaban con el mismo ancho?

Comment: Cualquiera de las dos maneras me sirve aunque para enriquecer el conocimiento me gustaría saber las 2 maneras si no es mucha molestia

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con el siguiente código, he agregado **nav-justified** y eliminado **nav-pills**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse " >
  <div class="navbar-header " id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
       <li role="presentation" ><a href="index.html">INICIO</a></li>
       <li role="presentation" ><a href="pacas.html">VENTA DE ROPA EN PACAS</a></li>
       <li role="presentation" ><a href="varon.html">VENTA DE ROPA PARA VARON</a></li>
       <li role="presentation" ><a href="dama.html">VENTA DE ROPA PARA DAMA</a></li>
       <li role="presentation" ><a href="nino.html">VENTA DE ROPA PARA NIÑO</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Sólo resta ajustar los colores de tu preferencia y reducir el valor **min-height** de la clase
 **.navbar**, por defecto es 50px.

Saludos!

Comment: muchisimas gracias me han servido de muchisima ayuda, como puedo modificar el min-height desde el css? seria 
.navbar {
 min-height: 30px;
}
realize ese codigo pero no cambia el tamaño de los li, y los colores aun no se como modificarlos podrian ayudarme en ese tema? les agradeceria muchisimo me han servido de mucho su ayuda!

Comment: Te recomiendo crear un segundo archivo CSS para tu código personalizado, puede llamarse **custom.css** o similar, debes agregarlo debajo del link de _Bootstrap_. Tu código es correcto.

Comment: Para cambiar el color de fondo y el color del texto usa las clases **.nav>li>a** y **.nav>li>a:hover**. Te será de gran utilidad una herramienta como _Firebug_ o similar para inspeccionar el código fuente de tu página en el navegador.

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente hay bastantes métodos para solucionar este problema. Aquí dejo un par de posibles alternativas dependiendo de si quieres que todos los elementos tenga el mismo o diferente ancho.

**1) Todos los elementos con el mismo tamaño**

Podrías hacer uso de [`nav-justified`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified) que hace que todos los elementos del `nav` ocupen el mismo ancho en el padre (y en ventanas/pantallas de menos de 768 pixels los muestra en vertical unos encima de otros).

> Nota: como se indica en el propio enlace de arriba, `nav-justified` no está soportado del todo y presenta bugs en Safari.

He aprovechado para limpiar un poco las clases innecesarias. Con esos cambios el código sería así:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse " >
  <div class="navbar-header " id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="index.html"><h4> INICIO</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="pacas.html"><h4> VENTA DE ROPA EN PACAS</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="varon.html"><h4> VENTA DE ROPA PARA VARON</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="dama.html"><h4> VENTA DE ROPA PARA DAMA</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="nino.html"><h4>VENTA DE ROPA PARA NIÑO</h4></a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

---

**2) Elementos con distinto tamaño**

En este caso lo que haríamos es hacer que el `ul` tenga un `display:table`, y los `li` un `display:table-cell`. Así se comportarán como si fueran las celdas de una tabla y el navegador las distribuirá como pueda para ajustarse al ancho de la pantalla.

El código quedaría así:

```css
ul.nav { display:table; width:100%; }
ul.nav > li { display:table-cell; float:none; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse " >
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="index.html"><h4> INICIO</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="pacas.html"><h4> VENTA DE ROPA EN PACAS</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="varon.html"><h4> VENTA DE ROPA PARA VARON</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="dama.html"><h4> VENTA DE ROPA PARA DAMA</h4></a></li>
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="nino.html"><h4>VENTA DE ROPA PARA NIÑO</h4></a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```